# How to call cdvirtualenv from a bash script?

Tags: bash, virtualenvwrapper

The virtualenv package is set up from .bashrc by sourcing `/usr/share.../virtualenvwrapper.sh`. This file defines a number of functions, among those `cdvirtualenv`:

```
function cdvirtualenv {
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home || return 1
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_active_environment || return 1
    virtualenvwrapper_cd "$VIRTUAL_ENV/$1"
}
```

How do I call this function from my own script file?

Simply calling it:

```
#!/bin/bash

cdvirtualenv
```

gives me:

```
/srv/bin$ ./echotmp.sh
./echotmp.sh: line 3: cdvirtualenv: command not found
```

Comment: If you just have a function definition lying around in some file, bash can not know anything about this function. You have to defined a bash function inside the bash process which is using that function.

Comment: @user1934428 I thought that it would inherit it from the calling environment (the file containing the function has been sourced during login from .bashrc ...)

Comment: See the bash man page on the `export` command: You indeed can inherit a **bash** function to a **bash** child process, but you have to use `export -f`. The reason is that **exporting** to a child process i a general Unix/Linux feature, and exporting a function betwen arbitrary processes does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you, to call `cdvirtualenv` from a bash script, you can use the source command to execute the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script and then call `cdvirtualenv` with the name of the virtual environment as an argument.